# Showing all results of custom content type in every page

Tags: nodes

Essentially we have a custom content type called "Slideshow" with "title", "content", and "image" as the three fields.  We want our admins to be able to add new elements to the slideshow by simply adding new content with the slideshow content type.

Everything we have tried has failed miserably. All research indicates that we need to create a custom node template named node--slideshow.tpl.php and lay it out how we want (IE place the slideshow divs around our render($content['field_slider_image']), etc... but how do we then insert that into our page template?

I apologize if this is a stupid question or if we're going about this in an odd way.  The template has already been coded, so we need to be able let our admins add slideshow elements easily and have them show up on the front-end without them editing a "slideshow" block.

I hope someone can help us figure this out.

**Edit** - Just stumbled upon "views" and that looks very promising because it allows us to set up a 'slideshow' view which automatically pulls in the content of our slideshow content type.  If we go that route, how do we format the output?

**Edit 2** - This slideshow will be at the top of the homepage only. Any other page will have the page title in that spot.

Comment: Give an example of where you want the slideshow to show up. I need to know if you should be making a block, template, view, etc.. What pages will it be on, will it be the same slideshow or different on different pages?

Comment: Just edited... Let me know if you need any  more info.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to to call [views_embed_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) in the page--front.tpl.php file (page-front.tpl.php in D6).

The more complex solution I would go with, is using [Panels everywhere](http://drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere), and expose the View as a content pane.